# Map: Direction in Mapkit to every Countries

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I want to give direction to every country as per apple documentation. But apple needs range GeoJson.

So, how to write this all location country GeoJson. It's getting too large.
Anyone guide me. How to get a route to all place Without uploading .geojson file to itunesconnect.

I already code for route.It's working.

But Routing App Coverage File is used for what purpose?

Why Apple say Geojson is compulsary. While app already give direction without it.

If i specify, the one country geojson file then apple going to give directional functionality to other country???

[image: Cities Name]

Thank you.

Comment: I am not getting, what you saying. Why we need to upload Routing App Coverage File??

Comment: You need to upload the routing file so that iOS knows in which regions do you want to provide coverage, [see the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH8-SW1). The question I linked here as a duplicate has the answer to your question about how to specify the entire world, without making your GeoJSON file too large.

Comment: if I specify only one country geojson, it will provide and work for another country also? Thank you for above answer.

Comment: if I want coverage for all country how can do?

Comment: Please read the question I linked in the first comment, there's an example for a GeoJson file that covers the whole world. You should be able to upload just that one file and provide directions for the entire world.

Comment: San Francisco and one around Chicago it's having only in geojson. Can you send me perfect place, where whole world geojson is there. I didn't found whole world geojson.

Comment: Can you please open the question linked as a duplicate and read the only answer posted there by Heider Sati?

Comment: Okay thank you Peter Tutervai. Got the answer.